# What datatype should be used for the Id primary key columns using a hilo generator and sql server?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, hilo

If I am using a hilo generator with nhibernate, what should the datatype for my id column be?  int or bigint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the data requirements? If you need more than 2 billion rows, including deletes/rollbacks then go bigint EDIT: I suppose you could start the identity at -2 billion and get double your pleasure

Comment: otherwise, an int will suffice.